# Libc crash on React native Android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

im facing an strange crash on app which im not able to find out its problem and what thing is causing this issue

facing such crashes on Libc.so libc-android.so and many other so files which are linked to it(maybe) a huge variety of devices are having this problem.

i tried many things to fix this issue like
use opacity:'99%' on react-native-webview
or androidLayerType etc.
Memory leak also a big concern on that but im not able to figure out while using with andorid studio profiler.
but none of things are working
[image]

```
Crashed: Thread: SIGSEGV  0x000000006d696e69
#00 pc 0x5e388 libhermes.so 
#01 pc 0x5e470 libhermes.so 
#02 pc 0x64738 libhermes.so 
#03 pc 0x628e8 libhermes.so 
#04 pc 0x641d4 libhermes.so 
#05 pc 0x5bf58 libhermes.so 
#06 pc 0x81f40 libhermes.so 
#07 pc 0x81574 libhermes.so 
#08 pc 0x81c8c libhermes.so 
#09 pc 0x81b70 libhermes.so 
#10 pc 0x4f074 libhermes.so 
#11 pc 0x50974 libhermes.so 
#12 pc 0x50130 libhermes.so 
#13 pc 0x36608 libhermes.so 
#14 pc 0x35ea8 libhermes.so 
#15 pc 0x26950 libhermes.so 
#16 pc 0x231dc libhermes-executor-release.so 
#17 pc 0x23038 libhermes-executor-release.so 
#18 pc 0x1c814 libhermes-executor-release.so 
#19 pc 0x1f0e4 libhermes-executor-release.so 
#20 pc 0x96f04 libreactnativejni.so 
#21 pc 0x980f0 libreactnativejni.so 
#22 pc 0x76794 libreactnativejni.so 
#23 pc 0x5e1b8 libreactnativejni.so 
#24 pc 0x5e130 libreactnativejni.so
```

my react-native deps.

```
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.67.4",
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from November 4th, 2022. React team at Facebook has made some changes that cause build failures on Android.

A quick fix for you is updating the react native version to `0.67.5`

You can explore the in-depth description of the issue and published  patches per react-native version -
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210

Comment: @Tanveerbyn check a new solution

Comment: but im not facing this issue while building apk. this is run time crash.